# Bind Table to item in array and repeat over instances

Tags: angularjs

I have a class structure as follows

```
data
   TeamList[]
      PlayerList[]
```

So what I have is a list inside a list. I want to be able to filter the TeamList with the value from a dropdown value, and iterate over the items in Player list as Rows. I am confident on the 2nd part with the following.

```
 <table style="border: 1px ">
            <tbody>
                <tr>
                    <td>Player Name</td>
                    <td>Position</td>
                    <td>Projected Points</td>
                </tr>
                <tr ng:repeat="e in data.Team.Roster | orderBy: '-ProjectedPoints' " ">
                        <td>{{e.Name}}</td>
                        <td>{{e.Position.Abbreviation}}</td>
                        <td>{{e.ProjectedPoints}}</td>
                    </tr>
                </tbody>
            </table>
```

But I am not sure how to get the "Team" in the above case to be correct. Is this something you can do in Angular, or are you better doing it on the JS side and pass the correct team back to the $scope?

Comment: create an `activeTeam` or similar named scope item in controller using `ng-change` trigger

Comment: Ok, I can do that. But how do I set the filter in the ng:repeat?

Comment: filter what? Not quite clear. You mentioned you had the second part sorted out

Comment: I mean the outputting the Players after I get the team. I guess I am not sure how to format the ng:repeat statement to filter based on the dropdown value.

Comment: aren't they a nested array in each team as shown above?

Comment: I was able to work around it. Thanks